# request parameter in get_object() in a Django mixin

Tags: django, mixins

I am writing a mixin where the instances of a model are filtered based on the logged in user. Is there a way I can access django's http request instance in get_object()? Or any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: You are talking about a class based view? It should be available as self.request.user

Comment: Yes. I had checked there, but I was doing something wrong. Now since you mentioned it again, I double checked and it's working. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It can be accessed via self.request.user